# Resolving the thunderbird phantom folder issue (gray, italics folders)

Tags: thunderbird

**Definition of "Phantom Folder":**
The term "Thunderbird Phantom Folder" seems to be a standard expression (and you will find hundreds of hits in google -- it's extremely strange that there is no StackOverflow entry for this yet). It refers to folders that appear in gray and italics font, and apart from possible subfolders, they do not contain mails. Phantom folders can not be deleted. Most importantly: *they do not exist!* This is why they are called "phantoms" because Thunderbird shows them although they are not for real.

**Some technical notes:**
I'm using Thunderbird 68.2.1 (64-Bit) under Ubuntu Linux. My IMAP mail account is run by "outlook" if that makes sense? (I'm not an admin...) I also have an outlook email client on another Windows computer, but it is being turned off while I'm experiencing or trying to fix these problems to prevent any side effects. None of the described issues appears "online" (in the outlook web mailer) or in the outlook mail client, it all just appears in Thunderbird.

**Standard Problem:**
Well, the problem is simply the "existence" of the phantom folders, i.e., that they are shown although they do not exist on the server. (I assume an IMAP server.) That is, the question everyone has is how to make Thunderbird understand that they are not real and thus to make it remove them.

**Solution:**
The internet is actually full of dozens or hundreds of posts, which essentially all tell the same (I think I've almost read them all^^). So please, just google "Thunderbird Phantom Folder". Anyway, here a short repetition of what you are supposed to do, but please don't expect details, just google it.

- delete the pancea.dat file
- delete all .msf files
- restart Thunderbird and enjoy life again!

From all that I've read this seems to work for pretty much everyone. But...

**My (Non-Standard?) Problem:**

[1] In a very nutshell, my problem is that all the countless google hits on my problem simply don't work on my system. Most importantly: All these solutions seem to suggest that it's a *local* problem with my *local* Thunderbird installation. After days of (unsuccessfully) following instructions, I started questioning that premise. So I've installed Thunderbird on a fresh PC and added my mail account. And it downloaded the phantom folders! So this proves it's *not* a local problem! Thunderbird must have uploaded the (flawed) folder list somewhere, which is probably the reason why deleting all the local Thunderbird files did not work as expected. Subsequent research suggested that my issue is related to the list of subscribed folders (later more).

[2] Furthermore, and this is extremely(!) annoying to me, *whenever* I rename a folder, Thunderbird creates a phantom.^^ So if I create "testfolder-1" and rename it into "testfolder-2", then I have both, where "folder-1" is a phantom that I can't delete. That behavior is also true for the phantoms themselves. So let's say I rename the phantom into "testfolder-1new", then I get a new phantom with that name whereas the old phantom "testfolder-1" remains as a phantom.

**Details/hints for solving the problem:**
As said, I believe that the problem might have to do with the list of subscribed folders. However, that doesn't really help me because in the subscription menu you only can check or uncheck the folder names, but I do not just want to not see them, I want the issue to be resolved. That is: what should be possible is that I can eliminate those wrong lines with the phantom folders and not just checking/unchecking the respective entries (but this is not possible anyway because the phantom lines do not have a checkbox next to them). An option like "re-compute the subscribed folder list" would solve the issue I suppose, but this does not exist. And, as said, deleting all the local files and then rebooting thunderbird does not help, so maybe it will just download the flawed subscription file(s) again. I would also like to note that there is an option in the account setting stating "show only subscribed folders". If you uncheck this, all folders on the server are shown. Non-surprisingly, the phantoms disappear (this is actually the reason why I believe the issue is caused by the subscription list). However, obviously I do not want to see all dozens of useless IMAP folders, I really do want to see only the subscribed folders. But if I switch back, i.e. enabling that option again, then sadly the phantoms re-appear.

**So, it all boils down to two questions, both of equal importance:**

1. How can I finally get rid of these phantom folders? More specifically: Is there a way to force Thunderbird to re-retrieve the folder list from the IMAP server?
2. How can I prevent Thunderbird from creating a phantom every f.... time I rename a folder? (And just because I am very interested: What is causing that error in the first place? Is it an actual Thunderbird bug?)

*I'd deeply appreciate the help, this is seriously driving me crazy.*

Comment: For the sake of completeness: This problem is already discussed in two *German* forum posts of the German Thunderbird forum:
(1) https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/82357-phantom-ordner/
(2) https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/83185-hochgeladene-d-h-nicht-lokal-erscheinende-phantomordner-phantomordner-erzeugung/?postID=452491#post452503
The latter one, (2), is from me and essentially exactly the same as this one (just the description is a bit shorter).

Comment: In that forum entry (2), a solution is suggested as well. Another user experienced the same problems and claims that he solved it. He discovered that there is a file called "subscriptions" on the server, which was faulty (it used inconsistent folder separators). After fixing this the problem disappeared. However, as a "normal user" you don't have access to that file... So I'll post news here in case I find out more.

Comment: **Question [1]:** is finally resolved, see anwser by ScottG. (THANK YOU!)
**Question [2]:** is ALSO resolved: That was apparently a bug caused by MS Outlook (the *service*, not the program! -- my mail address is hosted by outlook, but I still use Thunderbird). My admins contacted Microsoft and they fixed this bug! :) So, while I don't kow the details behind it, MS fixed the bug, so the problem is resolved and should not occur anymore. Thus, everybody still having phantom folders should be able to resolve this issue by following the answer to question [1] (by ScottG, below).

Comment: For me, subscribing to all the subfolders did not fix the problem (they were already checked). In my case I had in gmail a label named "x/y" (eg.) and the "/" was causing thunderbird to interpret the server path as a different folder (in this case x would be the parrent folder and y the child). Simply renaming the label (in gmail through browser) and restarting thunderbird solved the issue. I would post this as an answer but for some reason I am not allowed to..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Worked for me:

1. Right click on the account (ex. bobfliber@yahoo.com) in the folder pane
2. From the popup context menu, select 'Subscribe...'
3. A 'Folder List' menu pops up
4. Scroll the list for folders that have a bullet (i.e. no ✓) to the
   right
5. Click the bullet to change it to a check mark
6. Repeat as necessary
7. Click '**OK**'

Comment: Wow, that is true -- it works! Let me just add an important observation: I was in doubt whether this would *really* solve the problem because I was afraid that just unsubscribing the non-existent (thus phantom) folders would only not show it anymore, but it would still remain in the subscription list -- which would still be flawed because they do not exist! But no! Once you accept the selection (i.e., untick the phantom folders), close the menu, and open the list again, the phantom folders are completely gone! Yeah! :)

Comment: This worked for me as well, however in my case all items were checked. I unchecked and rechecked the Inbox folder, hit subscribe and Okay, and now it's repopulating the folder with years and years worth of messages that were no longer available.

Answer (score 8):

I just struggled with the same problem. I still don't have a full answer to
question 2, but I managed to solve problem 1:

> 1 How can I finally get rid of these phantom folders? More
>   specifically: Is there a way to force Thunderbird to re-retrieve the
>   folder list from the IMAP server?

Those phantom folders are, as you said, subscribed but don't exist anymore.
Indeed, if you turn on thunderbirds IMAP logging, you will see them listed as
(\Subscribed \NonExistent). The solution to get rid of those folders is
surprisingly simple: re-create them, then you can delete them!  (No joke)

Go the parent folder, and for every phantom subfolder create a new subfolder
of the same name (via context menu > new folder). As you do that, the folder's
appearance will change from grey italic back to normal again. After verifying
that the folders are empty, you can delete them and they will be gone entirely.

(This might give you a workaround for problem 2: instead of renaming a folder, create another one with the new name, move only the mails and then delete the old folder.)

> 2 How can I prevent Thunderbird from creating a phantom every f....
>   time I rename a folder? (And just because I am very interested: What
>   is causing that error in the first place? Is it an actual Thunderbird
>   bug?)

I agree with you that it is a server side problem: the list of subscribed folders
is out-of-sync with that list of actually existing folders. I am still not sure what
*causes* the problem, whether it's the client's or the server's fault. It might even
be an inherent design weakness of the IMAP protocol. It might also depend on some certain
constellations between client(s) and server. I am using thunderbird with several different
servers and with some of them I never had a problem with phantom folders.

Note: TIL that subscriptions actually exist has to do with the fact that the IMAP protocol
was also intended to be used for newsgroups, where it makes sense to subscribe only a
small subset of the lists. But in the context of a private mail account, subscriptions
seem to be a constant source of confusion. I have seen posts asking questions about
phantom folders which were eighteen years old.

Comment: I also had a phantom folder appearing: after renaming a folder (possibly from another mail client, but I don't remember for sure), the old folder name persisted as a phantom. The solution mentioned here, to create a new folder and name it the same as the phantom, allowed me to delete and get rid of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that I only get greyed out phantom folders in Thunderbird when I have tried to delete a folder that also contains a sub-folder. Thunderbird doesn't seem to like you deleting the main folder if you haven't deleted the subfolder first. If you do that, you can then go ahead and delete the greyed-out phantom main folder and it disappears for good.

Comment: Thanks, and +1. To be honest: I had the same problem (greyed out phantom folders) and as a long-term TB user doubted that your solution would work. But you're right: I really could simply delete those phantom folders. I had not tried that before, probably because it seemed too obvious :-) In my case, even deleting the greyed out root folder (instead of the subfolders first) worked without any issue.